# django tmeplate view is loading slow

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I have a template view `temrinal management` that hs 2 forms and 2 querysets, i am not doing any sorting stuff only a filtering method. I have no idea why the page goes slow, can it happen because of internet connection? I am using a mysql database that is on a separate server.

```
class TerminalManagementView(LoginRequiredMixin, TemplateView):
    template_name = "app/terminal_management.html"

    def post(request):
        pass

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['tb_terminal_categories'] = TbTerminalCategory.objects.all()
        context['tb_terminal_caregory_form'] = TbTerminalCategoryForm()
        context['tb_terminal_register_form'] = TbTerminalRegisterForm()
        filter = self.request.GET.get('category')
        if filter:
            terminals = TbTerminal.objects.all().filter(category__category_name=filter)
        else:
            terminals = TbTerminal.objects.all()

        page = self.request.GET.get('page', 1)
        paginator = Paginator(terminals, 9)

        try:
            data = paginator.page(page)
        except PageNotAnInteger:
            data = paginator.page(1)
        except EmptyPage:
            data = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

        context['terminals'] = data

        return context
```

```
class TbTerminal(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=32,
                          default=generate_uuid)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(
        TbCustomer, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='cstm_id')
    terminal_id = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True, null=True)
    area = models.ForeignKey(
        TbArea, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='extra_id1')
    room = models.ForeignKey(
        TbRoom, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='extra_id2')
    category = models.ForeignKey(
        TbTerminalCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='cat_id')
    firmware_version = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    total_space = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    free_space = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    program_version = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    device_model = models.ForeignKey(
        TbDeviceModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='device_model_id')
```

https://file.io/sJcQGq8ToX94

Comment: Show us your forms please.

Comment: Also the template would be helpful

Comment: the template is large, i will try to trim it

Comment: Do you by chance have any fields that are a foreign key to another table with lots of entries?

Comment: @EneP the TBTerminal has 4 foreign keys to other models. I have integrated django with the legacy database so yeah it has some fields. Can it cause that kind of problem?

Comment: I have added the models file

Comment: When you instantiate the forms, Django loads all possible choices inside the forms. So if you have lots of entries it can become very slow. Check to see how many choices you r select fields have.

Comment: I have added a link to the templates code

Comment: @EneP I have 6-8 choices in one form, and other form is a create form, so it;s just text input

Comment: Then I suggest you install https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/. It will show you exactly why it takes so long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the fields you're accessing from the template, you might benefit from using **select_related** on ForeignKey fields.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#select-related